# How to make a JPA sequence generate sequence Id in sync with external system using same DB concurrently

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, sequence

I am using a sequence which basically generates id b/w 1000 to 9999 while inserting record in database table. Now there is an external legacy system (GUI) which creates that record by manually mentioning id b/w 1000 to 9999.Before deploying my application there are already some records is table like below:

[image: Employee Table]

I have applied the sequence in my entity like below:

```
@Id
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "empid-sequence-generator",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "user_sequence"),
                    @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1000"),
                    @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
            }
    )
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "empid-sequence-generator")
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID", nullable = false)
    public short getEmp_id() {
        return emp_id;
    }
```

With the current sequence implementation I am getting SqlServerException due to primary key clashes some of id in the range(1000-9999) is already been inserted through External System GUI.

How can i implement the current sequence so that for the first insert record will be inserted with id 1000 as it's not occupied but for the next insert will save record with id 1002 as 1001 is already exist in DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Noting it as id generator can not do what you want, you would have to implement a function that returns the lowest available ID and call it every time you want to do an insert to obtain said id to set it to the entity manually.